# Can Wix Heat tool harvest files in two different folders?

Tags: wix, heat, harvest

I am using Harvest script which will take the files from a folder and deploy it to one of the folder.   Now we have a requirement that 9 files from this folder needs to be deployed to one folder and one file needs to be deployed to otheer folder.   I am using XSLT transformation but could not succeed. Can some one suggest how to do it?

Lines of code used to harvest my files

```
&"$Env:WIX\bin\heat.exe" dir "$dirForPrintedGuides" -cg CG_SPI_PRINTED_GUIDES -gg -sfrag -srd -sreg -var var.DocPrintedGuidesFolder -dr Inst_Help -t "$PSScriptRoot\FilterHarvestDocumentation.xslt"-out "$DocumentationPrintedGuidesHarvest"
```

Comment: Can you post the XSLT?

Comment: You will probably need to run heat twice with two different xslt transforms, one for the one folder removing that one file and one for the other folder removing all the other files.

Comment: Thanks. I used one more XSLT and it solved my purpose.